# Fetching users from db using asyncData()

Tags: mongodb, vue.js, mongoose, nuxt.js

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q04EB.png)

I want to fetch users from db using asyncAwait, But it gives me 404.

vue

```js
async asyncData({ $axios }) {
    let response = await $axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/getusers')

    return {
      users: response.data,
    }
  },
```

express

```js
router.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/getusers', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const users =  User.find({}).exec()

    res.status(200).json({ response: users })
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).json({ error: e.message })
  }
})
```

Comment: please provide the code as text not as screenshot

Comment: Ok, I updated it.

Comment: try to access this url `http://127.0.0.1:3000/getusers` directly

Answer (score 0):

404 is 'not found'. so I suggest that there's a problem with the url. Can you provide the error message too?

this is how I implement axios actions:

```
import axios from 'axios'
async (context) => {
        const res = await axios.get('https://yourlocal:3000/api/collections/do/smth', {
        headers: { //...}
        });
```

Comment: cors errors appears in the console, So somethings else, Does asyncData works with fetching db ?

Comment: if cors error is in the console, then that is your problem. The frontend cant reach the API because it is blocked by CORS.  Here is more about what is CORS -> https://medium.com/the-andela-way/what-exactly-is-cors-and-how-to-handle-it-fc2e52e89a0

Comment: No i meant to say No cors errors in the console, Sorry for my english.

Comment: What's the best method to fetch from db, Is it really asyncData or something else ?

Comment: it depends on context, if you could provide more details abt your problem, it would be easier to answer

Comment: Is the API running? can u access it from the browser?

Comment: The console gives me ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when i try with localhost:3000, And 404 (Not Found) when i try with http://127.0.0.1:3000/getusers

Comment: then the problem is with the server, not in your VUE. what about 127.0.0.1:3000 also 404?